# Problem with Adobe Illustrator when export *.ai to *svg, SVG file is lost small object items, flipped or lost character

Tags: svg, vector, adobe-illustrator

I have problem when convert from *.ai file to *svg, --> *.svg file result is incorrect ( not the same: lost small objects, image was flipped, lost characters ... )

[image]

[image]

[image]

Environment: 
OS: Windows 10, Mac OS 10.14.2 
Illustrator: Adobe Illustrator CC 2019

1. Select File -> Save as ... --> choose SVG ( svg ) --> click button "save"
2. SVG options dialog choose option like attach image.
3. click "OK" to save to SVG file

**Expected:** 
Display in SVG is the same with AI editor

**Actual:** 
+ SVG is lost some objects. 
+ SVG display not the same with AI Editor 
+ Lost character, Image is flip ..

Resource files: 
https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/AI-Files.zip

Here is my export options:
[image]

Please show me the way to resolve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried converting text to paths before you do the export?

Comment: A few things you can do: 1. those dark green paths that are missing: they may not be missing at all.They may be underneath the leafs or they may have the same or barely different color. Try putting them all in a group on top of the leafs group and use a different color, like yellow for example. You can change the color lately, in your svg file. For the HANOi text:search for the text on the svg file. I suppose it's a text on a path. Check the letter spacing you have and change it to a smaller value

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, @enxaneta, Could you show me how to fix case (Leaf vein is lost) ? Here is *.ai file: [lost_item_test.ai](https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/lost_item_test.zip), and here is exported *.svg file [lost_item_test.svg](https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/lost_item_test.svg)

Comment: I've opened your svg file. After deleting all the images I can see the leaf veins that are not lost but buried under the images. I would put all the images in a group and all the leaf veins in another group making sure that **in the svg file** the leaf veins group is below the images group

Comment: Hi @enxaneta, is there any way, we must only need update *.ai file & still get  correct result when export to *.svg file. ( because we automatic export *.ai to *.svg for another process )

Comment: You may try to organise your .ai file by putting all images in one group and all the leaf veins in another group